# Error while fetching JMX data (App Insights)

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-application-insights, jmx

I am trying to implement JMX metrics tracking using App Insights. Its a Spring Boot, Java application. This is my applicationinsights.json looks like:

```
{
  "connectionString":"SOME_URL",
  "role":{
    "name":"A_NAME",
    "instance":"AN_INSTANCE"
  },
  "sampling":{
    "requestsPerSecond":200
  },
  "jmxMetrics":[
    {
      "name":"TEMP - GC Thread Count",
      "objectName":"java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep",
      "attribute":"LastGcInfo.GcThreadCount"
    },
    {
      "name":"TEMP - GC Collection Count",
      "objectName":"java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep",
      "attribute":"CollectionCount"
    },
    {
      "name":"TEMP - Thread Count",
      "objectName":"java.lang:type=Threading",
      "attribute":"ThreadCount"
    }
  ],
  "instrumentation":{
    "logging":{
      "level":"INFO"
    },
    "micrometer":{
      "enabled":false
    },
    "jdbc":{
      "masking":{
        "enabled":true
      }
    },
    "kafka":{
      "enabled":true
    }
  },
  "heartbeat":{
    "intervalSeconds":60
  }
}
```

But I get this error when I start my application.

```
2023-10-05 12:59:18.075Z ERROR c.m.a.a.i.p.AbstractJmxPerformanceCounter - Error while fetching JMX data: 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find object name 'java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep''
```

I was trying this out from the tutorials. So I expected it to work. But somehow the JMX setup is throwing an error. It might be an error in syntax i guess.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your **applicationinsights.json** in my source code and I am able to run the java code which triggers the logs in Application Insights connected to my Azure Web app like below:-

**Code** :

***Application.java*** :

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

    @Bean
    public MyJmxBean myJmxBean() {
        return new MyJmxBean();
    }
}
```

***MyJmxBean.java*** :

```java
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedAttribute;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;

@ManagedResource(objectName = "com.demo:name=MyJmxBean")
public class MyJmxBean {
    private int counter = 0;

    @ManagedAttribute
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void incrementCounter() {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

***HomeController.java*** :

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Welcome to My Spring Boot Application!";
    }
}
```

***application.properties*** :

```json
spring.application.name=my-spring-boot-app
server.port=8080

spring.application-insights.instrumentation-key=<appinsights_instrumentationKey>
spring.jmx.enabled=true
```

***applicationinsights.json*** :

```json
{
    "connectionString":"<connec_string>",
    "role":{
      "name":"my-spring-boot-app",
      "instance":"1"
    },
    "sampling":{
      "requestsPerSecond":200
    },
    "jmxMetrics":[
      {
        "name":"TEMP - GC Thread Count",
        "objectName":"java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep",
        "attribute":"LastGcInfo.GcThreadCount"
      },
      {
        "name":"TEMP - GC Collection Count",
        "objectName":"java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep",
        "attribute":"CollectionCount"
      },
      {
        "name":"TEMP - Thread Count",
        "objectName":"java.lang:type=Threading",
        "attribute":"ThreadCount"
      }
    ],
    "instrumentation":{
      "logging":{
        "level":"INFO"
      },
      "micrometer":{
        "enabled":false
      },
      "jdbc":{
        "masking":{
          "enabled":true
        }
      },
      "kafka":{
        "enabled":true
      }
    },
    "heartbeat":{
      "intervalSeconds":60
    }
  }
```

**Output** :

It runs successfully as below:

[image]

***output URL*** :

[image]

Application Insights at the Azure Portal :

[image]

[image]